# For Each loop not echoing data (mysql_fetch_assoc problem?)

Tags: php, sql

Hello and Good Morning,

I am still learning PHP and for some reason my script will not post any data in my foreach loop. Any Idea why? The emailRow Echos out fine but I am going to remove My code is below:

```
<?php 

include 'includes/header.php';


$accountUser = array();
$upgradeEmail = $_GET['currEmail'];
$emailQuery = "SELECT fbID, firstName, lastName FROM users WHERE emailOne='".$upgradeEmail."' AND authLevel=0";

<?php echo $emailRow['fbID']; ?>
<?php echo $emailRow['firstName']; ?> 
<?php echo $emailRow['lastName']; ?>

 while($emailRow = mysql_fetch_assoc($emailQuery, $conn))
 {
    $accountUser[]=$emailRow;
 }
?> 
 <table>
<?php foreach($accountUser as $emailData) { ?>


<tr><td> <?php emailData['fbID']; ?> </td><td><?php emailData['firstName']; ?></td><td><?php emailData['lastName']; ?></td></tr>

<?php } ?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have constructed your SQL query in `$emailQuery`, but never executed it.  Call `mysql_query()`, and pass its result resource to `mysql_fetch_assoc()`.

```
$emailQuery = "SELECT fbID, firstName, lastName FROM users WHERE emailOne='".$upgradeEmail."' AND authLevel=0";
$result = mysql_query($emailQuery);
if ($result)
{
  while($emailRow = mysql_fetch_assoc($result, $conn))
  {
     $accountUser[]=$emailRow;
  }
}
else // your query failed
{
   // handle the failure
}
```

Please also be sure to protect your database from SQL injection by calling `mysql_real_escape_string()` on `$upgradeEmail` since you're receiving it from `$_GET.`

```
$upgradeEmail = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['currEmail']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually echo anything.
as well as not running the query.
and there are some other methods to do things, much cleaner than usual uglyPHP.

a function

```
function sqlArr($sql){
  $ret = array();
  $res = mysql_query($sql) or trigger_error(mysql_error()." ".$sql);
  if ($res) {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)){
      $ret[] = $row;
    }
  }
  return $ret;
}
```

a code

```
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['currEmail']);
$data  = sqlArr("SELECT * FROM users WHERE emailOne='$email' AND authLevel=0");
include 'template.php';
```

a template

```
<? include 'includes/header.php' ?>
<table>
<? foreach($data as $row) { ?>
  <tr>
     <td><?=$row['fbID']?></td>
     <td><?=$row['firstName']?></td>
     <td><?=$row['lastName']?></td>
  </tr>
<? } ?>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

*YOU HAVE A SYNTAX ERROR. You can't open a new php tag within an existing php tag.* You have to close the already open tag first.

As far as getting the query to work,

First you have to fetch data before printing it or echoing it...

```
while($emailRow = mysql_fetch_assoc($emailQuery, $conn))
{
$accountUser[]=$emailRow;
}
```

then you may write statements..

```
echo $emailRow['fbID']; etc. code.
```

Secondly you have not fired a query, just written the query statement. Use `mysql_query` to fire it.

Your code would be something like this..

```
  <?php include 'includes/header.php';

  $accountUser = array();
  $upgradeEmail = $_GET['currEmail'];
  $emailQuery = mysql_query("SELECT fbID, firstName, lastName FROM users WHERE emailOne='".$upgradeEmail."' AND authLevel=0") or die (mysql_error());
  while($emailRow = mysql_fetch_assoc($emailQuery, $conn))
   {
      $accountUser[]=$emailRow;
   }

  echo $emailRow['fbID'];
  echo $emailRow['firstName']; 
  echo $emailRow['lastName']; 
  print '<table>';
  foreach($accountUser as $emailData) {
  print '<tr><td>'$.emailData['fbID'].'</td><td>'.$emailData['firstName'].'</td><td>'.$emailData['lastName'].'</td></tr>';
  }
  print '</table';
   ?>
```

Feel free to use this code, modifying it to fit your needs.